# Java regex in capturing groups

Tags: java

```
  import java.util.regex.Matcher;
  import java.util.regex.Pattern;


  public class RegexMatches {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
    // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
    String line = "This order was placed for QT3000! OK?";
    String pattern = "(.*)(\\d+)(.*)";

    // Create a Pattern object
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

    // Now create matcher object.
    Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
    if (m.find()) {
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0));
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1));
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2));
    } else {
     System.out.println("NO MATCH");
    }
   }
  }
```

The output

> Found value: This order was placed for QT3000! OK?
>   Found value: This order was placed for QT300
>   Found value: 0

Please I want to understand this code in regular expression in java.

Comment: It woks fine or not? You need only number?

Comment: Group number 0 corresponds to the whole match. For the first capturing group, `.*` is greedy so it matches up to the end of the string, then backtracks until the rest of the regex can match, which happens when the second group matches at least one digit, which will be the last digit of `QT3000`. The third group which you aren't displaying matches `! OK?`

Comment: @oleg.cherednik I think OP wants someone to go throw the code and explain it all.

Comment: @achAmháin I think that expected result is illegal.

Comment: #group(0) matches the whole pattern. Indices start with 1 for this method.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to extract a number from the given string.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<prefix>\\D*)(?<number>\\d+)(?<suffix>\\D*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("This order was placed for QT3000! OK?");

if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println("Prefix: " + matcher.group("prefix"));  // Prefix: This order was placed for QT
    System.out.println("Number: " + matcher.group("number"));  // Number: 3000
    System.out.println("Suffix: " + matcher.group("suffix"));  // Suffix: ! OK?
} else
    System.out.println("NO MATCH");
```

In case you want to capture whole string, then you should use `Matcher.matcher()` to check *regular expression*.

```
if(matcher.matches()) {
    // string matches with regular expression
} else {
    // string does not match with regular expression
}
```

If you want to find multiple matches, then you should use `Matcher.hasNext()`.

```
while (matcher.matches()) {
    // next match found
}
```

[Demo at www.regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/twa5Ld/1)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as Aaron explained, the regex engine matches all the input string by first group. Secondly it backtracks to the find the part of the string matches with the second group and by just one digit the second group would be satisfied. Eventually, the rest of the string would be matched by the last group(3rd one).

Now Consider below code based on your sample code with some changes on pattern and one more printing statement:

```
String line = "This order was placed for QT3000! OK?";
String pattern = "(.*)(\\d{4})(.*)";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
if (m.find()) {
 System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0));
 System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1));
 System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2));
 System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(3));
} else {
 System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

**printing added statement**:  m.group(0) is equivalent of m.group() which means return all the matches of the given pattern in the given input string. By having such a pattern we have three other group indexes too. So by printing whole groups it can help us to find out what is happening right now by applying that pattern to that string.

**pattern change**: the change in the pattern can confirm the asserted statement about how the java regex engine works toward the original statement. So, the new pattern can select all the digits present in the input string and the output would change to below one:

> Found value: This order was placed for QT3000! OK?
>
> Found value: This order was placed for QT
>
> Found value: 3000
>
> Found value: ! OK?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Scanner class to parse the integers inside of a string of text. I also added utility methods to grow and fit an array.

```
import java.util.*;

public class NumberExtractor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "This order was placed for QT3000! OK?";
        int[] numbers = extractNumbers(test);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers)); // [ 3000 ]
    }

    public static int[] extractNumbers(String str) {
        return extractNumbers(str, 10);
    }

    public static int[] extractNumbers(String str, int defaultSize) {
        int count = 0;
        int[] result = new int[defaultSize];
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(str);
        scanner.useDelimiter("[^\\d]+"); // Number pattern
        while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            if (count == result.length) {
                result = growArray(result, 1.5f);
            }
            result[count++] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        scanner.close();
        return clipArray(result, count);
    }

    private static int[] growArray(int[] original, float growthPercent) {
        int[] copy = new int[(int) (original.length * growthPercent)];
        System.arraycopy(original, 0, copy, 0, Math.min(original.length, copy.length));
        return copy;
    }

    private static int[] clipArray(int[] original, int length) {
        return clipArray(original, 0, length);
    }

    private static int[] clipArray(int[] original, int start, int length) {
        int[] copy = new int[length];
        System.arraycopy(original, start, copy, 0, length);
        return copy;
    }
}
```